# Twilio - Change Default Ring Length Before Voicemail

Tags: twilio

I'm using the following Twimlet to direct all calls go to voicemail

```
http://twimlets.com/voicemail?Email=somebody@somedomain.com&Message=Please+Leave+A+Message
```

The voicemail picks up immediately. Is there a setting to make the phone ring for x seconds before voicemail kicks in without forwarding the calls to another number?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Unfortunately not with the Twimlet.  If you want to generate your own TwiML response you can use the [`<Pause>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/pause) to keep Twilio from answering the call right away.

Hope that helps.